# Convert method with loop for, without parameters, into a recursive method

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion

I have a working method `mostFrequent()` with loop 'for', but I need convert it to the same recursive method `mostFrequent()` without parameters:

```
public char mostFrequent()
    {
        int maxNum = 0;
        int num = 97;

        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            maxNum = howMany(num) //do something;
            num++;
        }
        return ...something;
    }
```

A method `howMany(num)` is recursive and I don't want to change it. I only need the same method `mostFrequent()`, recursive, without loops. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 26;    
int num = 97;
public char mostFrequent()
{
    if(i == 0)
        return .. something;
    int maxNum = 0;
    maxNum = howMany(num) //do something;
    num++;
    i--;

    mostFrequent();
}
```

I did what i could with the information i have, but this is recursive.

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but you're going backwards through i, and if backwards is acceptable, you have to start with i = 25.